# variable arguments in c++ with different datatypes

Tags: c++

please read through the following code

```
#define  INT    0
#define  CHAR   1
#define  FLOAT  2
#define  DOUBLE 3

int createKey(int keySize,vector<int> &types, ...){ 
    va_list varlist;
    va_start(varlist,types.size());

    int intKey;
    float floatKey;
    char charKey;
    double doubleKey;

    char *key = (char*)malloc(keySize);
    int offset = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<types.size();i++){
        switch(types[i]){
            case INT:
                intKey = va_arg(varlist,int);
                memcpy(&key[offset],&intKey,sizeof(int));
                offset += sizeof(int);
            break;

            case CHAR:
                charKey = va_arg(varlist,char);
                memcpy(&key[offset],&charKey,sizeof(char));
                offset += sizeof(char);
            break;

            case FLOAT:
                floatKey = va_arg(varlist,float);
                memcpy(&key[offset],&floatKey,sizeof(float));
                offset += sizeof(float);
            break;

            case DOUBLE:
                doubleKey = va_arg(varlist,double);
                memcpy(&key[offset],&doubleKey,sizeof(double));
                offset += sizeof(double);
            break;

        }
        va_end(varlist);
    }

    int testIntKey;
    char testCharKey;
    float testFloatKey;
    double testDoubleKey;

    offset = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<types.size();i++) {
        switch(types[i]){
            case INT:
                memcpy(&testIntKey,&key[offset],sizeof(int));
                cout<<testIntKey<<endl;
                offset += sizeof(int);
            break;

            case CHAR:
                memcpy(&testCharKey,&key[offset],sizeof(char));
                cout<<testCharKey<<endl;
                offset += sizeof(char);

            break;

            case FLOAT:
                memcpy(&testFloatKey,&key[offset],sizeof(float));
                cout<<testFloatKey<<endl;
                offset += sizeof(float);
            break;

            case DOUBLE:
                memcpy(&testDoubleKey,&key[offset],sizeof(double));
                cout<<testDoubleKey<<endl;
                offset += sizeof(double);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

In the above code, I am trying to create a key that is a combination of one or more of the datatypes(int,char,float,double)...I used ellipses as i donot know the number of arguments that may be passed to createKey(). Now the above code when compiled shows the following warnings..

```
varargsTest.cpp: In function ‘int createKey(int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, ...)’:
varargsTest.cpp:20: warning: second parameter of ‘va_start’ not last named argument
varargsTest.cpp:39: warning: ‘char’ is promoted to ‘int’ when passed through ‘...’
varargsTest.cpp:39: note: (so you should pass ‘int’ not ‘char’ to ‘va_arg’)
varargsTest.cpp:39: note: if this code is reached, the program will abort
varargsTest.cpp:45: warning: ‘float’ is promoted to ‘double’ when passed through ‘...’
varargsTest.cpp:45: note: if this code is reached, the program will abort
```

and when i run the program with the following ..

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> types;

    types.push_back(INT);
    types.push_back(CHAR);
    types.push_back(INT);

    createKey(9,types,85,'s',97);

}
```

I get `Illegal instruction.`

How could this problem be solved...Is this the right approach to handle these kind of problems?

Comment: It is best to avoid variadic functions in C++ unless you have a compiler that supports variadic templates.  Variadic functions are just not worth the trouble.

Comment: Thank u for ur comments...But how could i solve this problem without using variadic arguments...Any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: Overload `operator<<` like `std::ostream` does.

Comment: i cant get u..can u plz elaborate on what u mean to say..with a working example?

Comment: You can't use `va_arg(varlist, float)` because the types are promoted to double; you must use `va_arg(varlist, double)`, just like the error message says.  Similarly, `short` and `char` types are promoted to `int` and must be retrieved using `int`.

Comment: Ya i understood that through the error messages..But then how would i do it for types like float,shot and char types???

Comment: this looks like come C hack, but not proper C++. The code design should avoid the *need* for variable arguments lists. You could use a templated push() function of similar which works on one argument (which may be different) at a time.

Answer (score 4):

When you call a function with a variable argument list (which is generally a bad idea in C++), then any `float` expressions are automatically promoted (converted) to `double`, and any `char` (any of the three flavours) and `short` (two flavours) are promoted to `int`.  Therefore, as the error message says, you cannot expect `va_arg()` to collect a `float` or a `char` type; you need to collect a `double` or `int` and coerce the result if necessary.

In general, C++ programmers look unfavourably on variable argument list functions because they are inherently not type-safe and C++ invests a lot of effort into being type-safe.

The 1998 C++ standard essentially incorporates the (1989) C standard specification for `<stdarg.h>` verbatim.  The 1999 C standard says:

> ### §7.15.1.1 The va_arg macro
>
> #### Synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <stdarg.h>
> type va_arg(va_list ap, type);
> ```
>
> #### Description
>
> The `va_arg` macro expands to an expression that has the specified type and the value of
>   the next argument in the call. The parameter `ap` shall have been initialized by the
>   `va_start` or `va_copy` macro (without an intervening invocation of the `va_end`<sup>212)</sup>
>   macro for the same `ap`). Each invocation of the `va_arg` macro modifies `ap` so that the
>   values of successive arguments are returned in turn. The parameter `type` shall be a type
>   name specified such that the type of a pointer to an object that has the specified type can
>   be obtained simply by postfixing a `*` to `type`. If there is no actual next argument, or if
>   `type` is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according
>   to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined, except for the following
>   cases:
>
> — one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;
>
> — one type is pointer to void and the other is a pointer to a character type.
>
> #### Returns
>
> The first invocation of the `va_arg` macro after that of the `va_start` macro returns the
>   value of the argument after that specified by `parmN`. Successive invocations return the
>   values of the remaining arguments in succession.
>
> <sup>212)</sup> It is permitted to create a pointer to a va_list and pass that pointer to another function, in which
>   case the original function may make further use of the original list after the other function returns.

The C89 standard is similar but does not support/define `va_copy`.